# c++ open gl shader failed compilation

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader

Im trying to learn a gl in cpp and trying to create some shaders reading its documentation and following a yt tutorial.
It just had a compilation fail.
yestarday it was just printing in console Shader " + filePath + " failed to Compile
Today it printing that :

> ERROR: 0:7: 'gl_position' : undeclared identifier
>   ERROR: 0:7: 'xy' : field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left
>    hand side
>   ERROR: 0:7: 'assign' :  cannot convert from '2-component vector of highp float'
>   to 'highp float'
>   ERROR: 0:8: 'z' : field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left
>   hand side 
>   ERROR: 0:9: 'w' : field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left
>   hand side

Shader shaders/colorShading.vert failed to Compile
Enter any key to quit...

this is my shader source code:

```
#version 130

in vec2 vertexPosition;

void main()
{
    gl_position.xy = vertexPosition * 2;
    gl_position.z = 0.0;
    gl_position.w = 1.0;
}
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
#include "GLSLProgram.h"
#include "Error.h"

#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

GLSLProgram::GLSLProgram() :_numAttributes(0), _programID(0), _vertexShaderID(0), _fragmentShaderID(0)
{
}


GLSLProgram::~GLSLProgram()
{

}

void GLSLProgram::compileShaders(const std::string& vertexShaderFilePath, const std::string& framgmentShaderFilePath)
{
    _vertexShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    if (_vertexShaderID == 0)
    {
        fatalError("Vertex shader failed to be created!");
    }

    _fragmentShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    if (_fragmentShaderID == 0)
    {

        fatalError("Fragment shader failed to be created!");
    }



    compileShader(vertexShaderFilePath, _vertexShaderID);
    compileShader(framgmentShaderFilePath, _fragmentShaderID);
}

void GLSLProgram::linkShaders()
{

    // Attach Shaders to Program
    glAttachShader(_programID, _vertexShaderID);
    glAttachShader(_programID, _fragmentShaderID);

    // Link the Program.
    glLinkProgram(_programID);

    GLuint isLinked = 0;
    glGetProgramiv(_programID, GL_LINK_STATUS, (int *)&isLinked);
    if (GL_FALSE == isLinked) {

        GLint maxLength = 0;
        glGetProgramiv(_programID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &maxLength);

        std::vector<char> errorLog(maxLength);
        glGetProgramInfoLog(_programID, maxLength, &maxLength, &errorLog[0]);

        glDeleteProgram(_programID);
        glDeleteShader(_vertexShaderID);
        glDeleteShader(_fragmentShaderID);

        std::printf("%s\n", &(errorLog[0]));
        fatalError("Shaders failed to link!");

        return;

    }

    glDetachShader(_programID, _vertexShaderID);
    glDetachShader(_programID, _fragmentShaderID);
    glDeleteShader(_vertexShaderID);
    glDeleteShader(_fragmentShaderID);

}

void GLSLProgram::addAttribute(const std::string& attributeName)
{
    glBindAttribLocation(_programID, _numAttributes++, attributeName.c_str());
}

void GLSLProgram::use()
{
    glUseProgram(_programID);
    for (int i = 0; i < _numAttributes; i++)
    {
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(i);
    }
}

void GLSLProgram::unuse()
{
    glUseProgram(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < _numAttributes; i++)
    {
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(i);
    }
}

void GLSLProgram::compileShader(const std::string & filePath, GLuint& id)
{
    std::ifstream fileptr(filePath);
    if (fileptr.fail()) {
        // Not sold on this
        perror(filePath.c_str());
        fatalError("Failed to Open " + filePath);
    }

    std::string fileContents = "";
    std::string line;

    while (std::getline(fileptr, line))
    {
        fileContents += line + "\n";
    }

    fileptr.close();

    // This is weird
    const GLchar * contentsPtr = fileContents.c_str();
    glShaderSource(id, 1, &contentsPtr, 0);

    glCompileShader(id);

    GLint success = 0;
    glGetShaderiv(id, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);

    if (success == GL_FALSE) {

        GLint maxLength = 0;
        glGetShaderiv(id, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &maxLength);

        std::vector<GLchar> errorLog(maxLength);
        glGetShaderInfoLog(id, maxLength, &maxLength, &errorLog[0]);

        glDeleteShader(id);

        std::printf("%s\n", &(errorLog[0]));
        fatalError("Shader " + filePath + " failed to Compile");
    }
}
```

Comment: The shader is failing to compile, but we don't have its source code...

Comment: *"ERROR: 0:7: 'gl_position' "*, it has to be `gl_Position`, GLSL is case sensitive

Comment: Indeed, just a typo: https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Built-in_Variable_(GLSL)

Answer (score 3):

The vertex shader failed to compile, because it has to be `gl_Position` instead of `gl_position`. GLSL is case sensitive. See [Vertex Shader - Outputs](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Shader#Outputs):

```
void main()
{
    gl_Position.xy = vertexPosition * 2;
    gl_Position.z = 0.0;
    gl_Position.w = 1.0;
}
```

Comment: You are right! Thank you.
now it says: ERROR: 0:8: 'constructor' : too many arguments


Shader shaders/colorShading.frag failed to Compile
Enter any key to quit...

Comment: @IliasKarypidis This is an error in the fragment shader. Pleas show your fragment shader too

Comment: now the problem is solved but i get and ms visual c++ runtime library error. debug assertion failed! expression:vector subscrit out of range

Comment: can anyone help me ?

Comment: @IliasKarypidis No, not without any specific information. *"debug assertion failed"* can be anywhere in your program. You have to debug your program. Where happens the debug assertion. Apart from that, that's a new question.